# VB.NET LogOn Redirect Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have the following code:

```
//redirect based on whether the user is admin, company owner, or blog owner
Dim userRole As String = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Membership.GetUser.UserName)(0)
Debug.Print(userRole)
If userRole Is "Administrator" Then
    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Company")
Else
    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
End If
```

The value for userRole outputs "Administrator" and I am comparing it to "Administrator" however it's not redirecting to the Company controller, instead it's going to "Home."

How can I fix this?  Thank you!

Note:  I also tried this, but it also doesn't execute the redirect:

```
If String.Compare(userRole, "Administrator") Then
```

Comment: Does your Company page load if you just put http://yoursite/Index/Company into your browser? This could be a routing issue, so maybe check your Global.asax . Is the Company page within a different area?

Comment: Yes, the page loads fine and Eric Robinson's answer is correct.  I would like to understand why.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `if userRole = "Administrator" then` instead I think that might solve you issue.

Comment: That is correct!  Please tell me why both of my attempts don't work, if you know.

Comment: 'is' should only be used for null or not null checks

Comment: What Chris said! lol I honestly didn't know the specifics of `=` vs `is` but its true that I only is for checking if things are null.
Good luck with your project.

Comment: `Is` should only be used to compare Object references.  Your userRole is a string, "Administrator" is *another* string. But they are not the same string. they just happen to have the same content.  Which is why `is` returns false.

Comment: What about the String.Compare(userRole, "Administrator")?  Wouldn't that eval to true?